Есть ли в python turtle условный оператор для проверки, находится ли черепаха на нарисованной линии?
Собственно вопрос: Есть ли в python turtle условный оператор для проверки, находится ли черепаха на нарисованной линии?
цель: улучшение кода для задач из ЕГЭ

Какую задачу вы решаете?

Примерно такого рода:Черепаха выполнила следующую программу:
Налево 255
Повтори 3 [Налево 30 Повтори 4 [Вперёд 10 Налево 90] ]
Определите, общее количество различных точек с целочисленными координатами, которые будут находиться на пересечении только двух фигур, полученных при выполнении данной программы. Точки на линиях учитывать не следует.

Часто точки бывают очень близко к линии и не всегда понятно засчитывать их или нет. Поэтому думал, нет ли возможности не отрисовывывать точки сетки которые находятся точно на линии.

В этой задаче черепашка не нужна. Нужно написать программу, которая соберёт вместе все клетки, которые черешка заполнила бы следуя по указанной траектории.

Наводящий вопрос: вы можете определить сколько клеток закрасит черепаха? Если клетка красится несколько раз, учитывайте их все.

Проблема не в этом, я знаю, что такое пересечение. Я про задачи где линия какой-либо фигуры может проходить на расстоянии 0.01 от точки которую мне надо посчитать если она внутри фигуры, и в отличии от кумира, в python turtle даже при большом масштабе не всегда это хорошо видно. Поэтому возникает вопрос может ли черепашка как-то чекать, стоит ли она на уже нарисованной линии, чтобы понять стоит ли ей закрашивать спорную точку с целочисленными координатами?

В задаче все точки целочисленные.
